# TypeError numpy dtype int

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, int, ceil

Hello i have a verry simple problem. but i don't understand what cause the problem.

I have the following python(3) script. i have numpy 1.13.1(an old one but my problem with `dtype` should work).
according to [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-kwargs) the dtype exist in `ufunc` since 1.6

```
import numpy as np

M=1001

N = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M))

N
Out[252]: 1024.0

2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=int)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-253-4b982a04c884>", line 1, in <module>
    2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=int)

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc ceil




2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=float)
Out[254]: 1024.0




2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=np.float64)
Out[256]: 1024.0

2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=np.float32)
Out[257]: 1024.0

2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=np.int64)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-258-9902fa43f3ac>", line 1, in <module>
    2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=np.int64)

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc ceil




2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=np.int32)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-259-8a2f2834384f>", line 1, in <module>
    2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(M),dtype=np.int32)

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc ceil
```

As you can see when i change the `dtype` to `int`, `int32` or `int64` it fails. Probably anything other than `float` fails. I would guess this shouldn't do that!
I can add a small fix so that `int(np.ceil(...))` the result is what i want.

1. I want to know what cause this problem? Since i don't read anything in the numpy reference manual about any issue with this([numpy reference ceil](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html#numpy.ceil)).
2. If Possible to do solve this problem that it works the way i started

Thanks

Comment: Think about what `ceil` is doing, it makes no sense to do it for `int`.  When you specify the `dtype`, you aren't just specifying the return type, but the dtype the calculation is done with as well.  Feel free to change the result to an integer after the calculation has been done, but what you are seeing currently is expected.  Some better discussion [here](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/floor-with-dtype-td44734.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails simply has to do with how `dtype` is treated by numpy ufuncs.  It does not only override the output dtype, but the ***dtype of the calculation*** as well.  The `ceil` ufunc doesn't support calculations involving integers, so it fails:

[From the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-kwargs) for ufunc `kwargs`:

> **`dtype`**
>
> Overrides the dtype of the calculation and output arrays. Similar to signature.